# How to get result column from varchar expression

Tags: mysql, sql

I have varchar column in my MySQL database and values are:

| exp |
| --- |
| `'2+3'` |
| `'4+5'` |
| `'7+1'` |

How can I get results of these expressions, so I want new int column:

| exp | res |
| --- | --- |
| `'2+3'` | `5` |
| `'4+5'` | `9` |
| `'7+1'` | `8` |

Comment: I don't think there's anything built into MySQL that will evaluate expressions. You could write a stored function that uses `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` to create dynamic SQL that does it.

Comment: Does the column value really contain literal quote characters?

Comment: Will it always be integer plus integer?

Comment: No, it doesn't contain literal quote characters.

Comment: @jarlh Yes, it always be integer plus integer.

Comment: Check out SUBSTR and POSITION functions, or whatever MySQL has.

Comment: you want the new column as the result of a select, or you want it added to your table?  what's your table name?  you indicate in a comment that there might be more than two numbers; how many numbers might there be?  can you edit your question to show better examples of all the possible data?

Answer (score 1):

Since it's always just adding two numbers, you don't need any fancy evaluation. Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to get the strings before and after the `+`. Then add them. The `+` operator will automatically convert the strings to numbers.

```
SELECT exp, SUBSTRING_INDEX(exp, '+', 1) + SUBSTRING_INDEX(exp, '+', -1) AS res
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: And what if I have more than 2 values, like 4+5+6+7+8+9+1?

Comment: Then it's not very simple. You could write a stored function to loop over them.

Comment: You might be able to do it with a recursive CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Not a simpkle solution, but as function don't allow dynamic sql i had to use stored procedure. It needs still some work if you want more

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab
>     (`exp` varchar(7))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tab
>     (`exp`)
> VALUES
>     ('2+3'),
>     ('4+5'),
>     ('7+1')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE additf() 
>
> BEGIN
>       DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
>        DECLARE expres VARCHAR(100);
>   -- declare cursor
>   DEClARE curexp 
>       CURSOR FOR 
>           SELECT exp FROM tab;
>
>   -- declare NOT FOUND handler
>   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
>         FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;
>     DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS adtemo;
>     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE adtemo ( exp varchar(10), res DOUBLE);
>
>   OPEN curexp;
>
>   getres: LOOP
>       FETCH curexp INTO expres;
>       IF finished = 1 THEN 
>           LEAVE getres;
>       END IF;
>     SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ' ,expres, '  INTO @int;');
>     PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
>     EXECUTE stmt;
> INSERT INTO adtemo VALUES (expres,@int);
>     END LOOP getres;
>   CLOSE curexp;
>
>     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL additf()
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECt * FROM adtemo
> ```
>
> ```
> exp | res
> :-- | --:
> 2+3 |   5
> 4+5 |   9
> 7+1 |   8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fdaf19d59d585574b330aed6abe1c1de)*